# Terminal menus supporting Mnemonic Keys

Tags: command-line, menu

[Mnemonics keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonics_(keyboard)): are the underlined characters in a context menu. This is popular in GUI menus, e.g: `Alt+e, n` in Firefox opens settings. For more concrete example, I'm looking for a program `mnemonic_menu` that acts like `dmenu` or `fzf` such that:

```
echo -e "{A}pple\n{O}range\n{B}anana" | mnemonic_menu
```

results in showing interactive selection with A, O, and B as its mnemonic keys. i.e: if `a` is pressed, it immediately exists, outputting the corresponding selection: `Apple`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.